# Previous block hash on first Bitcoin block?

Tags: genesis-block, block-header

The bitcoin-explorer command `bx fetch-header -t 1` fetches the first Bitcoin block and shows the block header.
If I check the "first" block header, where does "previous block hash" come from?

[image: bx fetch-header]

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution, the command for the genesis block should be:

`bx fetch-header -t 0`

[image: bx fetch-header genesis block]